# jitsi-meet [conference.js] <e.value>: CONFERENCE FAILED: conference.videobridgeNotAvailable

Tags: jitsi

[JitsiMeetJS.js] :  UnhandledError: null Script: null Line: null Column: null StackTrace:  Error: Jingle error: {"reason":"item-not-found","source":"F4:00:92:03:36:0B:29:40:08:03:DC:54:DC:BE:29:F3:2E:48:9F:58:BB:FE:D2:04:D4:0D:F3:39:4C:90:C7:9EF4:00:92:03:36:0B:29:40:08:03:DC:54:DC:BE:29:F3:2E:48:9F:58:BB:FE:D2:04:D4:0D:F3:39:4C:90:C7:9E","session":"JingleSessionPC[p2p=true,initiator=true,sid=524aaa3890f5]"}

Comment: Please elaborate your question more.

Comment: This means you don't seem to have any Jitsi Videobridge available. Make sure it's running, and restar it just in case.